# For loop ...help

Tags: java

Can someone help me understand this loop?

```
byte tempBuffer[] = new byte[64*1024];

for (int i = 0; i < tempBuffer.length; i++) {
    wavPanel.addAudioByte(tempBuffer[i]);
}
```

In my opinion it works like this:

- cycle as many times as the size of tempBuffer 
  in the meantime
- fill the tempBuffer with bytes or maybe execute the `addAudioByte()` method of the `wavPanel` object n times

Sorry for my confusion.

Can someone tell me, in words, what the loop does?

Thanks in advance.

Carlos Frerera

Answer (score 9):

The byte array has size 64*1024 so the loop is executed 64*1024 times. Every time the loop executes, the next byte from the byte array is passed to the method addAudioByte (starting with the 0th. element) as a parameter.

What the method addAudioByte(byte byt) does, is depending on the implementation of this method.

To answer your question you asked in the last answer:

byte b stands for the parameter which is passed to your method addAudioByte(...). This means to call this method you have to pass the datatype byte to this method. [This link](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) explains the byte data type.

Answer (score 7):

It calls

```
wavPanel.addAudioByte(...)
```

for each of the 64*1024 (65536) bytes in the tempBuffer, like so:

```
wavPanel.addAuditByte(tempBuffer[0]);
wavPanel.addAuditByte(tempBuffer[1]);
wavPanel.addAuditByte(tempBuffer[2]);
wavPanel.addAuditByte(tempBuffer[3]);
wavPanel.addAuditByte(tempBuffer[4]);
....
```

eventually ending on the 64*1024-1 byte

```
...
wavPanel.addAuditByte(tempBuffer[65535]);
```

Remember, that while there are 65*1024 bytes in this array, since arrays start their indexing a 0, you can't ask for the 65536th index, because if you counted them starting at zero, it would `tempBuffer[65536]` would actually be the *65537th* byte

Answer (score 1):

Here's a smaller example to show the basics. Lets take a smaller array with just four values:

```
byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[4];
tempBuffer[0] = 10;
tempBuffer[1] = 10;
tempBuffer[2] = 10;
tempBuffer[3] = 10;
```

`tempBuffer.length` is the size of the array (4 slots), the index of the first value in the array is `0`, the index of the last one is `(tempBuffer.length-1) = 3`.

Now the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tempBuffer.length; i++) {
  // do something
}
```

This will loop 4 times and `i` will be incremented by 1 on each iteration. So in the first iteration, i is `0`, in the last one, `i` has a value od `3`.

```
wavPanel.addAudioByte(tempBuffer[i]);
```

This is the last 'java magic'. tempBuffer[i] is the value of the ith 'slot' in the array, so if `i` is `0`, `tempBuffer[0]` is `10` (according to our initialization). And this value is passed to the method `wavPanel.addAudioByte(byte b)`.