# How do I modify this code statement?

Tags: java

I do need your help.

I've got this code:

```
File f1 = openFile("Choose file one",
        JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG);
    if (f1 == null)
        return;
    File f2 = openFile("Choose file two",
        JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG);
    if (f2 == null)
        return;

        File f3 = openFile("Choose destination",
        JFileChooser.SAVE_DIALOG);
    if (f3 == null)
       return;
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Files are now joined in"
           + f3.getName());
```

I'd like to get rid of this :

```
File f3 = openFile("Choose destination",
        JFileChooser.SAVE_DIALOG);
    if (f3 == null)
       return;
```

and use the following code statement , this way , but unfortunately I get errors ..!

```
OptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Files are now joined in"
           + f1.getName() + f2.getName());
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Which errors? I mean, to say it in more than 15 chars: Which errors?

Comment: What errors are you getting?  You're missing the J in JOptionPane.

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve with your change?

Comment: Just because its "ugly" does not mean that there is a syntax, bug, or error... just readability. If it works - ship it to your customer.  Then go back later and refactor if necessary.

Comment: I'd like to be able to give the joined file (f3) a composed name .
I mean if a choose the first file whose name is "chord.wav" and then 
I choose the second one whose name is "phone.wav" , the resulting file 
after joinning should be : "chord+phone.wav".
Actuallu the user shouldn't be able to set the file name, but the output file name should be as I mentioned above.

Comment: Ulrike? Carlos? who are you? --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187390/for-loop-help/3192479#3192479

Comment: @ulrike - you can easily join 2 files in Windows (DOS) using `copy /B chord.wav+phone.wav chord+phone.wav`  (`/B` is used to indicate binary mode)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *add* the file names, you need to split the name from the extension first. use the ´lastIndexOf`method to find the '.' and`substring` to get only the name part:

```
    ...
    if (f2 == null)
        return;

    String newName = fileName(f1) + "+" + f2.getName();  // assuming extension of f2
   // or   newName = fileName(f1) + "+" + fileName(f2) + ".wav";
    File f3 = new File(newName);
    ...

private static String fileName(File file) {
    String name = file.getName();
    int index = name.lastIndexOf('.');
    if (index != -1) {
        name = name.substring(0, index);
    }
    return name;
}
```

Similar to get the extension (`name.substring(index+1)`) and check if both extensions are equal (if required).

<sup>English is not my first (neither second) language, corrections are welcome</sup>

**EDIT**
*but I don't believe that just joining two WAVs will produce a working one. I suspect you need to remove the header from the second WAV and actualize the first one...*

Answer (score 0):

You really need to be more specific, what errors do you get? How do your final code look like excactly?

You will get an error if you refer to f3 after removing the declaration, also, as mentioned by Mathew, you miss the "j" in JOptionPane.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Files are now joined in"
       + f1.getName() + f2.getName());
```

should compile if `this` is a subclass of `Composite`. Assuming the input file f1 and f2 are `path/file1.wav` and `path/file2.wav`, the message will be

```
 Files are now joined infile1.wavfile2.wav
```